# Random-order minting of ERC721 tokens

Tags: solidity, nft, chainlink, mint, vrf

Problem is minting of tokens in random order. I would like to hear more about drawbacks of these approaches:

Having:

- **10.000 NFT collectibles**
- **amongst them there are rare ones**
- **images are clearly showing this rarity**
- **metadata + images are revealed after sell-out**

1/ Effortless way is to save metadata+images to ipfs in randomized order [3856, 17, 6668, 735..] but with sorted ids as 1 .. 10000. I don't like the fact that operators know exact location of rare ones, and that makes me uneasy.

2/ Mint starts in order 1 .. 10000, metadata is not uploaded yet. After sell-out, contract method using ChainLink VRF is called, and it generate random numbers which assign rarity to tokens with these ids. Then metadata is uploaded to ipfs, then reveal. I don't like that ipfs CID update, though.

3/ Also ChainLink VRF, but in every call of `mint` function. Might get expensive with pricing = 2 LINK / token.

I understand that no solution is perfect, but is there any better way to go when minting tokens in random order?

*EDIT: I ended up using slightly different solution, described it here: [repository](https://gitlab.com/xplsek03/lucky-time-walkers-nft)*

Answer (score 1):

You can go for option 3, but use a single call to chainlink and then expand the random number for each token number. Thanks how I did it in the Wavelength contract here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x68930072647a0d79e601d5ee3914833ae9148247#code

Relevant line is 2423. Hope that helps.

Comment: That way the numbers are not predictable by users or the project team. I used the plant seed function after it sold out and it saved a ton of link.

Comment: Exactly the same thing I ended up with. Nice thinking, although had some problem explaining people why have I done this because they even couldn't understand they might be bad players :D

Comment: Hi, @Fatlion, I've been reviewing your contract and the getSeed function in line 2423 but I don't understand how it is related to minting each token. I see that plantSeed starts the Chainlink VRF process by calling requestRandomness and the corresponding fulfillRandomness sets the state variable baseSeed to the random number returned by Chainlink but I can't see how all the pieces fit together.

Is this supposed to be a mint in two steps with users minting first and some time later the owner triggering a reveal by calling a function?

Could you please add some more details?